# Getting from string id to valid enum value in typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following enum:

```
export enum Probability {
    Certain = 1,
    AlmostCertain = 2,
    Likely = 3,
    Unlikely = 4,
    AlmostImpossible = 5,
    Impossible = 6,
}
```

The numbers get referenced in dropdowns so when I retrieve the value I get "1","2" etc.

The problem I am having is then trying to use that value "as" the enum.

So for instance:

```
export function probabilityLabel(probability: Probability): string {
    switch (probability) {
        case Probability.Certain:
            return "Certain";
        case Probability.AlmostCertain:
            return "Almost Certain";
```

And then calling it something along the lines of:
probabilityLabel(this.form.get('probability').value)//so basically passing in "1"

This isn't matching.

How can I go about getting from "1" to something that will match when passed in?

A few of the ways I have tried...
ProbabilityLabel("1");

let probability: Probability = Probability["1"];

console.log("second attempt", ProbabilityLabel(probability));

I've created a replicable plunkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/8sGJeDGL0wmgBU9WxtQ4?p=preview

Comment: `console.log("first attempt", ProbabilityLabel(1));` use number? If you show the real use-case we can give a more detailed answer I guess.

Comment: I've given a plunkr with this not working? The string value is coming from a reactive form which isn't relevant to solving the problem, I end up with a string value. Are you saying just convert that to a number?

Comment: yes exactly, like `Number("1")`

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Probability {
    Certain = 1,
    AlmostCertain = 2,
    Likely = 3,
    Unlikely = 4,
    AlmostImpossible = 5,
    Impossible = 6
}
let p:Probability;
p = Probability.Unlikely;
alert(Probability[p]);
enum Probability2 {
    Certain,
    AlmostCertain,
    Likely,
    Unlikely,
    AlmostImpossible,
    Impossible
}
let p2:Probability2;
p2 = Probability.Unlikely;
alert(Probability[p2]);
let s: string = Probability[p2];
alert(s);
let p3: Probability2 = Probability[Probability[s]];
alert(p3);
let p4: Probability2 = [Probability[s]];
alert(p4); // Will be number
```

See [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html#enums-and-numbers) You can run this code in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Probability%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Certain%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AlmostCertain%20%3D%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Likely%20%3D%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Unlikely%20%3D%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AlmostImpossible%20%3D%205%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Impossible%20%3D%206%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20p%3AProbability%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20p%20%3D%20Probability.Unlikely%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(Probability%5Bp%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%20Probability2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Certain%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AlmostCertain%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Likely%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Unlikely%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AlmostImpossible%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Impossible%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20p2%3AProbability2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p2%20%3D%20Probability.Unlikely%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(Probability%5Bp2%5D)%3B).

(**Unfortunately the code gets truncated with some sort of URL limit, but you can copy/paste from above and run it in the playground**)

BTW You don't need numbers on all values in enum. First one will be offset. So Certain = 5, would make AlmostCertain 6, Likely 7 etc.

If you do p4:Probability2 = Probability[s] you'd get a number if you alert it

Comment: Thanks for this. I do need numbers though. They will be a reference id in the database so I need to keep those. Also as mentioned I am getting the id as a string from a reactive form control so am trying to get from a string version of a number through to the enum value that will match in a switch.